# OpenGL - Shadow map/Depth Map giving weird result

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, depth-buffer, shadow-mapping

I'm trying to render my depth map, for now I've rendered it onto the objects in the scene to get a overview of what the result I'm getting is. From what I've learned, the black values are objects that are close to the light, and white is further away. Please correct me if I've gotten it wrong. This is the result I'm getting:[Shadow map rendered onto a cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwdYQ.jpg)

With this result, I speculate that I've created the framebuffer in the wrong way. this is how I generate it:

```
void createFrameBuffer()
{
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBuffer);


    glGenTextures(1, &DepthMap);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, DepthMap);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,
        SHADOW_WIDTH, SHADOW_HEIGHT, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,                                 
        GL_TEXTURE_2D, DepthMap, 0);

    glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
    glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

We have followed the [Learn OpenGL - Shadow Mapping](https://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-Lighting/Shadows/Shadow-Mapping) tutorial, and our shaders looks almost identical to his. So there shouldn't be any problem there. I think I've misunderstood something in the CPU part of shadow mapping, and not the GPU.This is how I draw everything, set up matrices and use programs.

```
float orthoValue = 20.0f;

glm::mat4 lightProjection = glm::ortho(-orthoValue,
    orthoValue, -orthoValue, orthoValue, NEARPLANE, FARPLANE);
glm::mat4 lightView = glm::lookAt(lightPos, glm::vec3(0.0f),
    glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0f, 0.0));
glm::mat4 lightSpaceMatrix = lightProjection * lightView;
//lightSpaceMatrix[3] = glm::vec4(lightPos, 1.0f);

if (shadows == true) {

    glUseProgram(sShaderProgram);
    glBindVertexArray(mesh.VAO);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
    glViewport(0, 0, SHADOW_WIDTH, SHADOW_HEIGHT);
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);


    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(sShaderProgram, "lightSpaceMatrix"),
        1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(lightSpaceMatrix));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(sShaderProgram, "modelMatrix"),
        1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(mesh.modelMatrix));

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, mesh.vertices.size());
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    setViewPort();
}
```

I'm really grateful for all of the tips and help in advance. If I've left out crucial information, I'll add whatever's missing.

**More code of the rendering part edit, also edited the way we draw:**

This is the main loop

```
                glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1);
                glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
                glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

                //Keyboard input
                keyPressed();
                //Mouse movement
                MousePointer();

                lightProjection = glm::ortho(-orthoValue,
                    orthoValue, -orthoValue, orthoValue, NEARPLANE, FARPLANE);
                glm::lookAt(lightPos, glm::vec3(0.0f),
                    glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
                lightSpaceMatrix = lightProjection * lightView;

                glUseProgram(sShaderProgram);
                glViewport(0, 0, SHADOW_WIDTH, SHADOW_HEIGHT);
                glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
                glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

                glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, DepthMap);

                GLint samplerLoc = glGetUniformLocation(sShaderProgram, "DepthMap");
                glUniform1i(samplerLoc, 0);

                glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(sShaderProgram, "lightSpaceMatrix"),
                    1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(lightSpaceMatrix));

                for (int i = 0; i < objmesh.size(); i++) {
                    RenderShadows(*objmesh[i]);
                }
                glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
                setViewPort();
                glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                //glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

                for (int i = 0; i < objmesh.size(); i++){
                    RenderVertices(gShaderProgram, *objmesh[i], true);
                }

            }
```

Here we have the RenderShadows function that uses the shadow glsl program:

```
void RenderShadows(OBJMeshes mesh){
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(sShaderProgram, "modelMatrix"),
    1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(mesh.modelMatrix));

glBindVertexArray(mesh.VAO);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, mesh.vertices.size());
glBindVertexArray(0);

}
```

And finally the normal render function that renders the geometry:

```
void RenderVertices(GLuint shaderProgram, OBJMeshes mesh, bool shadows) {

GLuint CPUValuesID = glGetUniformLocation(gUbo, "MVP");

glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, gUbo);
glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(CPUMatricies), &globalCPU);

glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, mtlBuff);
glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(mtlValues), &mtl);

glUniformMatrix4fv(CPUValuesID, 1, GL_FALSE, &globalCPU.MVP[0][0]);

glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
glBindVertexArray(mesh.VAO);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mesh.texture);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, DepthMap);

GLint samplerLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "DepthMap");
glUniform1i(samplerLoc, 1);

glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "modelMatrix"),
    1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(mesh.modelMatrix));
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "lightSpaceMatrix"),
    1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(lightSpaceMatrix));

glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "lightPos"), lightPos.x, lightPos.y, lightPos.z);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, mesh.vertices.size());

glBindVertexArray(0);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to render your depth buffer to a texture you have to bind a texture with `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT` format to the 
render buffer of your frame buffer buffer. What you did was to bind a texture to color plan 0 of your frame buffer, because you used `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` to bind the texture in your code.

```
glFramebufferTexture2D( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, ColorMap0, 0 );
```

What you have to do is to create a render buffer and bind it to your frame buffer.

```
GLuint frameBuffer;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);

GLuint renderbuffer;
glGenRenderbuffers( 1, &renderbuffer );
glBindRenderbuffer( GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderbuffer );
```

Then you have to bind your depth texture to the frame buffer using `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT`:

```
glFramebufferTexture2D( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, DepthMap, 0 );
```

Note that you can bind separate textures for the deep buffer and all color planes to the frame buffer.

After you have done this correctly you have to draw your scene and fill your buffers and/or textures.

```
// enable the depth test
glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );

// bind frame buffer and clear the frame buffer  and the depth buffer
glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer );
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)`

// draw the scene
// ...

// unbind frame buffer
glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0 );

// clear the drawing buffer and the depth buffer
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
```

After your frame buffer has been *unbind*, you can use its textures as input for your shadow pass.

To bind the texture to the shader, you have to bind the texture to a texture unit and assign the index of the texture unit to the uniform sampler of the shader.

Bind the texture to a texture unit:

```
GLuint DepthMap;
int textureUnit = 1; 
glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 + textureUnit );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, DepthMap );
```

Use the program and assign the index of the texture unit to the uniform sampler:

```
GLuint depthProg = ...;
glUseProgram( depthProg );

GLint depthSamplerLocation = glGetUniformLocation( u_depthAttachment );
glUniform1i( depthSamplerLocation, textureUnit );
```

## Extension of the answer

There are some more issues in your code:

In the main loop you clear the frame buffer `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` before you call `RenderShadows`, but inside the function you bind a frame buffer `glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);`, so the clearing is useless.

In `RenderShadows` you try to bind the `DepthMap` texture to a texture sampler,
but the `DepthMap` texture is the target texture of the currently bound frame buffer. A texture can't be source and destination at the same time, this would cause undefined behavior.

In `RenderVertices` you have to assign the **index of the texture unit** to the 
texture sampler not the texture object:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, DepthMap);

GLint samplerLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "DepthMap");
// glUniform1i(samplerLoc, DepthMap); <- this is wrong
glUniform1i(samplerLoc, 1); // 1 because the texture is bound to GL_TEXTURE1
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the long answer! I tried to do how you said it, but it seems it doesn't work. I added a plane, and I'm putting the DepthMap as a texture on it but it doesn't have anything on it. If I use GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 it turns black, if I use the GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT it's all gray. Could it be that the DepthMap isn't getting anything from the shadows vertex/fragment shader?

Comment: Depth test is enabled (before the creation of the framebuffer), and I changed around in the rendering to make it more easy to see. I added the code of my rendering if you feel like you have time to check it out, it starts after the bold text. Thank you for all your help, it means a lot!

Comment: I've added an updated code and I actually get a result that seems somewhat reasonable! Thank you so much for all the help, I've been stuck at this for longer than I dare to admit! Right now it looks like this [link](http://imgur.com/a/GHNMu). Now it seems like it's the perspective that's off, because the picture in the screenshot is taken at the lights position. Thank you again!

Comment: It sure is! You've helped me a lot and made me come up to the solution and understanding of my question! I'll mark it as acceptable, although I'm not sure why the color on the plane is only black and not some gray gradient color, and why my Shadow isn't showing from the objects on the ground plane right now. It's like the function inside the fragment shader isn't properly working. But I'll see if I can find it out myself for now. Mind if I message you back otherwise?

Comment: @Haplue The best way to get an answer is to ask a question on stackoverflow because a large number of users have the ability to answer the question, including me.